# почему не работает redirect Django

Tags: django, redirect, backend

у меня есть такой код из views.py который написан с помощью документации, но он не работает и вместо редиректа на главную страницу выдет в адресной строке только '/?'. Помогите пожалуйста сказав что нужно изменить потому что я только начина. разбираться в джанго и не понимаю.

'''

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages


def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        return redirect('/main/')
    else:
        return redirect('signin')
return render(request, 'main_page/index.html')


def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main_page/main.html')
```

'''
urls проекта

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from main_page.views import index, main

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('main_page.urls')),


]
```

urls приложения

```
from django.urls import path, include
from main_page.views import index, main

urlpatterns = [
path('main/', main, name='home'),
path('signin/', index, name='signin'),


]
```

шаблон

```
{%load static%}

<!doctype html>

...<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" 
 placeholder="name@example.com">
  <label for="floatingInput"><font color="#bf7a00">Email</font></label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" 
placeholder="Password">
  <label for="floatingPassword"><font color="#bf7a00">Password</font> 
</label>
</div>...
```

вот моя форма

```
<form>
<img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'main_page/images/img.png'%}" 
alt="" width="72" height="57">
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal"> <font color="orange">Please sign 
in</font></h1>

<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" 
 placeholder="name@example.com">
  <label for="floatingInput"><font color="#bf7a00">Email</font> 
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" 
 placeholder="Password">
  <label for="floatingPassword"><font 
 color="#bf7a00">Password</font></label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox mb-3">
  <label>
    <input style='color: orange' type="checkbox" value="remember- 
 me"> <font color="orange">Remember me</font>
  </label>
</div>
<button  style="background: purple; border: 0; " class="w-100 btn 
btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"> <font color="orange">Sign 
in</font> 
</button>
<p  class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted"> <font color="orange">&copy; 2017– 
2022</font></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Покажите urls, покажите шаблон с формой

Comment: добавил коментарий

Comment: Лучше использовать url-name. В редирект укажите name вашего '/main/'

Comment: В показанном вами html-коде есть поля ввода, но нет собственно формы. Вы отправляете запрос через ajax или что вообще у вас происходит?

Comment: уже пробовал name все тоже самое происходит

Comment: я взял код с bootstrap и у меня вроде все работало делал  по гайду, а потом перестало вот хотел бы узнать что не так

Comment: Покажите, как вы отправляете запрос. В показанном вами html-коде нет формы и в таком виде он не способен отправить запрос в Django

Comment: получается никак :|, а что нужно дописать

Comment: Значит Django тут ни при чём и вам нужно куда-то [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms) или конкретнее [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Comment: я нашел форму добавил в вопрос

Comment: В форме не указано, на какой адрес она отправляется (по умолчанию будет текущий) и не указан тип запроса (по умолчанию будет GET). Логично, что никакого редиректа не будет, ведь в Django вы прописали выполнение редиректов только при POST-запросе. А ещё вы не указали имена полей, поэтому форма отправляется полностью пустая — и именно поэтому вы видите `/?` в адресной строке

Comment: а как нужно изменить форму чтобы она отправялась в  нужный адрес

Comment: я добавил в форму method Post и csrf_token и при нажитии на кнопку теперь на сайте выдаёт ошибку                                                                                                                       
MultiValueDictKeyError at /signin/
'email'

Comment: Потому что в вашей форме нет поля с именем email, да

Comment: a type='email' не полe с именем email

Comment: как исправить то

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `redirect("/main/")` используйте `redirect('home')`

Answer (score 0):

Ответ таков что нужно использовать для входа уже существующего пользователя из админ панели таблицы  пользователи